# How to resize gradually a sticky header on scroll starting from a defined position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, conditional-statements

I created a design with a sticky header that resizes itself gradually when the user scrolls down. It works very nice because the sticky header does not cover the content below until it gets the minimal height. Take a look at my example:

https://jsfiddle.net/gerardbm/8hvw40g3/12/

The problem is the header should resize gradually when the user scrolls down **starting from a defined initial position** (higher than `0`). My design has a topbar of `40px` height over the header, so the resizing event must start from the pixel 40 (in vertical). The initial height of the header is `90px` and it must resize until it has a height of `60px`.

This is the code I'm using to try to achieve this. It works partially, the header covers the content below; before the header is fully resized.

```
// Start after the vertical position 40px
if (st > 40) { 
    // Resize the header between positions 40px and 70px
    if (st < 70 ) {
        // Calculate the new header height (simple maths)
        newH = 90 - st + 40;
    } else {
        // Keep the new height (resized)
        newH = 60;
    }

    if (newH < 60) {
        newH = 60;
    }

    elements.css({'height': newH + 'px', 'lineHeight': newH + 'px'});

} else {
    // Recover the original height of the header
    newH = 90;
    elements.css({'height': newH + 'px', 'lineHeight': newH + 'px'});
}
```

The variable `st` contains the `scrollTop` value. The full code is in the *jsfiddle*.

*Clarifying:* What does it mean 'gradually'? Pixel by pixel, so, if the user scrolls down at the pixel 40, the header height will be `90px` (the initial height); when the user scrolls down at the pixel 41, the header height will be `89px`, and so on. At the end, the user scrolls down at the pixel 70 and the header height will be `60px`.

**Edit:** This is an example of what I want. See how the header starts to change the height after scrolling up the full topbar (`34px` in its case), and not from the top of the webpage (`0px`):

http://seventhqueen.com/themes/kleo/404

Comment: the scroll does not happen one pixel at a time so you may have to tweak the code to find the best scrollTop value

Comment: You'll notice that it works as expected when using the scrollbar instead of mousewheel. It already looks correct with smooth scroll Mozilla. Chrome scrolls about 165 pixels at a time for example, with only a single event fired. Something similar you could do instead is to apply a class and a CSS height `transition`.

Comment: @Shikkediel, well, that's not a problem because I'm using the plugin smoothscroll for Google Chrome (https://github.com/galambalazs/smoothscroll-for-websites). What I need is that the header starts to change the size when the scroll position is at `40px` and not from the top of the webpage (0px). Like this one: http://seventhqueen.com/themes/kleo/404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading what you described, I think you're looking for this `if` `else` statement :

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qw7unmxy/)

```
if (st <= 40) newH = menu;
else if (st <= 70) newH = menu - st + 40;
else newH = 60;
```

I think it could likely be improved a bit by adding a flag or a class if more than 70 pixels have been scrolled. Depending on that, you could apply the new style or not. That way it won't try to set it when it's already in place. Less relevant for the first 70 pixels. And jQuery is already quite smart with that.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Now the resize starts from the position 40! This conditional is smart and efficient. But during the resizing event the content is still covered. I'm not sure, but it seems we would need to push down the content below while the header is being resized.

Comment: Cheers, have a look at this then... it applies an equal and opposite bit of padding to the text so it virtually stands still while the header is transitioned in size. https://jsfiddle.net/3x6dwptL/

Comment: That's awesome! Now it works totally perfect. Thanks 1000 times!

Comment: Glad to help out. It's a nice subtle effect, the kind I like exactly. :-)

Comment: Just a little ask related to it: do you use the operator `<=` because of the `border-bottom`? I suppose the `scrollTop` starts to count the pixels from `1`, so if I implement this code in a design without a `border-bottom`, then I should use simply this operator: `<` (to have one pixel less). Is it right? Thanks! :)

Comment: I thought about that a bit and explicitly added it - not so much related to the menu's border but to the height of the top bar. It's a tiny detail that could be a brain teaser nonetheless. Effectively it probably doesn't make a difference... I figured that at the 40th pixel there was nothing to resize yet so made it start a pixel later. If you fill in 40 in the `else` statement, you will end up with what's in the previous `if` exactly. Thought it was slightly more correct that way. You could do `< 41` as well of course or disregard the aforementioned.

Comment: Same consideration for `st <= 70` by the way, it's probably even more abundant there. Sizes look correct for the rest with regard to the border because of using `box-sizing`. Good point there though, something I probably spent more time on than necessary when putting it together - too freaky for detail.

Comment: «I figured that at the 40th pixel there was nothing to resize yet so made it start a pixel later.» Yes, that makes sense and it seems the logical way. Now that's more clear for me, thanks again! :)